# What's the best way to keep line breaks from a form entry to mysql and handle mysql escapes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question I have been pondering for a while.

What is the best way of keeping line breaks to a MySQL db and handle the escapes so that the query doesn't fail.

I came up with a function to do this but I am not sure this is the right way to handle the string.

```
function nl2br2 ($string){
    $sqlescapes = array("'", ";");
    $string = str_replace($sqlescapes, "", $string); 
    return str_replace( "\n", '<br />', $string ); 
}
```

This function will replace PHP line breaks and replace them with `<br/>` so html can recognise them if I use mysqli_real_escape_string it removes the line break and this is the predicament.

Are there any other functions I could utilise, as the above removes grammar from the string?

Comment: Try [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in PDO

Comment: Can you show how you're attempting to use this function?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your thoughts what this function will do is replace PHP line breaks and replace them with <br/> so html can recognise them if I use mysqli_real_escape_string it removes the line break and this is the predicament

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string does not remove line breask

Comment: When I used mysqli_real_escape_string it saved incorrectly and didn't preserve the line breaks

Comment: then your doing something else

Comment: checked PHP.net line breaks are escaped?
The string to be escaped.
Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Comment: escaped, NOT removed

Comment: Sorry how do I unescape these? Stripslashes?

Comment: you dont, its purely for inserting the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100713/discussion-between-d-jones-and-dagon).